# How do you display a button on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a main div which internally consists of many child divs.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
<div class="list-group" id="recentList">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">a.pdf</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;"></button>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Now, on mouse over of child div, I want to display the button btn-trash and on click of that button I want to remove the child div.

I tried something like this. But its not working!!!

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#recentList.list-group-item', function() {
  //alert('mouse entered')
  $(this).find(".btn-trash").show();
})
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#recentList.list-group-item', function () {
  alert('mouse left')
    $(this).find(".btn-trash").hide();
});
```

Comment: You are just missing a space between `#recentList` and `.list-group-item` as `.list-group-item` is a child of `#recentList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#recentList").hover(function(){
    $('.btn-trash',this).show();
  },function(){$('.btn-trash',this).hide();})
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#recentList").hover(function(){
    $('.btn-trash',this).show();
  },function(){$('.btn-trash',this).hide();})
})
```

```css
.list-group { border:2px solid orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="recentList">
  <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
    <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
    <a class="a-file">a.pdf</a>
    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;">current</button>
    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;">star</button>
    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">trash</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use mouseover & mouseout.. Try this

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#recentList.list-group-item', function() {
  alert('mouse entered')
  $(this).find(".btn-trash").show();
})
$(document).on('mouseout', '#recentList.list-group-item', function () {
  alert('mouse left')
    $(this).find(".btn-trash").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#recentList').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(".btn-trash").show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
       $(".btn-trash").hide();
    });
});
```

Try this on fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4abq9rg5/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".list-group-item").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children(".btn-trash").show();
    });
    $(".list-group-item").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children(".btn-trash").hide();
    });
    $(".btn-trash").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="recentList">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">a.pdf</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">trash</button>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">a.pdf</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-trash glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">trash</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can do this and on click of trash button child div will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.list-group-item', function() {
  //alert('mouse entered')
  $(this).find(".btn-trash").show();
}).on('mouseout',function(){
 $(this).find(".btn-trash").hide();
})

$(document).on('click', '.btn-trash', function() {
 $(this).closest('.list-group-item').remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" id="recentList">
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">1111111111111</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;">Star</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">Trash</button>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">22222222222222</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;">Star</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">Trash</button>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="list-group-item" style="border-left: none; border-right: none;">
        <img class="a-img" src="./img/desktop.png" height="25" width="25">
        <a class="a-file">333333333333333</a>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn-sm btn-current btn-default" style="float: right;">Ok</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-star btn-sm btn-star btn-default" style="float: right;">Star</button>
        <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm btn-trash btn-default" style="display: none;">Trash</button>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

This will work if there are multiple child divs also, as you said there will be many child divs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the selector:

`#recentList.list-group-item`

you need to add space between `#recentList` and `.list-group-item`
or add *grater than* sigh between them.

or you could just remove  `#recentList` and stick with `.list-group-item` only.

Tested and worked fine.

`#recentList.list-group-item` (without space or grater than sign)
means selecting element which has **Id** `recentList` and **Class** `list-group-item` together.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers for this question. I usually do this by controlling the `display` css rule on the element. `display: block` is to show, `display: none` is to hide.

Note the `space` in the selector. If you do not leave a space `"#recentList.list-group-item"`, the selector is unresolved, use `"#recentList .list-group-item"` instead.

Instead of `find` you can directly select the `class` (ie. `btn-trash`). If it matches multiple elements, then you must use ID instead of selecting by class values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#recentList .list-group-item").mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("mouse entered");
    $(".btn-trash").css("display","block");
});

$("#recentList .list-group-item").mouseleave(function(){
    console.log("mouse left");
    $(".btn-trash").css("display","none");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button class="my-button">Click button</button>
```

```css
.my-button{
  height:5px;
  width:10px
  background-color:fff;
  color:fff;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.my-button hover{
  background-color:red;
  color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a space between #recentList and .list-group-item

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#recentList .list-group-item', function() {
  //alert('mouse entered')
  $(this).find(".btn-trash").show();
})
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#recentList .list-group-item', function () {
  alert('mouse left')
    $(this).find(".btn-trash").hide();
});
```

and check in this URL : https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47419/